# How to make javascript generated HTML indexable by google crawlers?

Tags: java, jquery, struts2, seo, google-crawlers

I have a webform with a header navigation.

To generate this header navigation, I make a **AJAX** call to a **Java** class and get a JSON string as a response.

I Parse the string and create the HTML in jQuery. Below is an example:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/test/newHeaderJSON',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('ul.main-menu').append('<a href="'+ obj.header.headerItems.productMenu.link +'">' + obj.header.headerItems.productMenu.name + '</a>');
            }
        });
    });
```

The above example shows an anchor tag being added to the page via jQuery.

Now comes the problem. This anchor is not seen in the page source and hence not crawl-able.

I want to make this component crawl-able.

I have read about the _escape_fragment_ but whatever i could find online, I could not make much sense of it.

Can someone tell me how this method is used in a more understandable way?

Below is the alternate way that I used using the jsp struts2 iterator. Even in this method, I am not getting the values on source. The code works for the DOM but not source.

```
 <html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          $.get('test/newHeader');
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <s:iterator value="%{menuOptions.get('Home_Improvement').productgroup}" var="productGroupVar">
            <a href="<test:sRelativeUrl url='/${productGroupVar.groupId}'/>">${productGroupVar.name}</a>
        </s:iterator>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Is there any real need to generate the link via javascript? If you want to make your html "crawl-able", I'd strongly suggest to generate the output on the server side rather than trying to hack things around.

Comment: The content for the links are coming from a content system. We do not know at any point of time, how many links will be there. It can change anytime based on business needs. So we cant just add anchor tags on HTML as we do not know how many will be there. And the second approach can be to generate the HTML in backend which is never a recommended way.

Comment: You probably want to read this article: [Making Ajax Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/).

Comment: Hey jfriend00, I have gone through this link. BUT I cannot use third party like HtmlUnit in my case.:(

Comment: Any reason to make ajax call?

Comment: (1) The content is dynamic. (2) I do not know how many anchors tags to generate (3) Generating HTML from Java will be a very bad practice

Comment: Nobody tries to get you to generate html on the server if it's not nessesary but you could use struts2 features to access the action data from JSP.

Comment: Ya i tried the iterator of struts2 but it doesnt show up on the html page source as well as it is after the jsp is rendered. Hence I am back to square 1.

Comment: Could you post the code you used?

Comment: SagarBhat, @RomanC is right. The article linked by jfriend00 is amazing, and it is a must-read when making ajax-applications, but as you described your requisites, ajax is not necessary, not even remotely. Ajax for a navigation bar ? Just use Struts2 Tags / OGNL! And in a non-struts2 environment, just use JSTL / JSP EL... :&

Comment: Ive edited my original post to show the struts tags. I am not much familiar with struts. My primary area is jQuery. So if you guys have any pointers, feel free :)

Comment: @SagarBhat But server applications don't work with pure javascript?! What a server technology you know?

Comment: I can work with Java. Need some pointers. This needs to be developed with Java as backend technology.

Comment: For this purpose post the action code that is used to render the JSP above, post `struts.xml`, so we could see many details about configuration and flow. How could anybody know what is the objects you deal with?

Comment: Thanx for all the inputs and sorry for the late reply. Struts 2 did help me out :) .  Added an action in the jsp and using the Struts iterator, the thing worked :) . Thanx a lot for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

> This anchor is not seen in the page source and hence not crawl-able.

Google is capable of crawling pages generated from Javascript. Hence, your statement is not correct. So if the URL(s) to that/those page(s) are available in a `sitemap.xml`, then there is no issue.